# SQL to give the more recently inserted record

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table with columns id, username, timestamp.

```
ID     Username       timestamp
1      aaa            10/10/2009
1      bbb            12/10/2010
2      ccc            10/11/2009
2      ddd            12/10/2010
2      eee            12/05/2011
3      kkk            04/03/2012
```

The output should be giving us the ID, username that was most recently inserted.

```
1      bbb            12/10/2010
2      eee            12/05/2011
3      kkk            04/03/2012
```

I thought of using the Join to do this. But is there a more efficient query i can write?

Comment: joins are efficient, databases are designed to use joins.

Answer (score 2):

You can use analytic functions

```
SELECT id,
       username,
       timestamp
  FROM (SELECT id,
               username,
               timestamp,
               rank() over (partition by id
                                order by timestamp desc) rnk
          FROM your_table_name )
 WHERE rnk = 1;
```

If there is the possibility of a tie (two rows with the same `id` and `timestamp`), this will return both rows.  You could expand the `order by` to specify which of the tied rows you wanted or you could switch to using the `row_number` analytic function rather than `rank` to get one of the tied rows arbitrarily.

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfect. I however did a partition on username as well. Just in casr we have a duplicate username inserted on the same day.

Comment: @mahen - If you partition by `username` and `id`, every row in your sample table would be returned, not just the three you said you wanted.

Comment: This is what i am doing. SELECT  DISTINCT USER_PRFLE_ID,
            USER_NM AS TSYS_USER_NAME
FROM
(SELECT ps.USER_PRFLE_ID,
            ps.BUS_APPL_ID,
            ps.USER_NM,
            ps.EFF_STRT_TS,
            RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY ps.USER_PRFLE_ID, ps.BUS_APPL_ID ORDER BY ps.EFF_STRT_TS DESC, ps.USER_NM DESC) rnk
FROM   USER_PRFLE_SNGL_SIGNON_REF PARTITION (PTN_C30000101) ps,
            BUS_APPL_REF ba
WHERE ps.VLD_IND = 'Y'
            AND ps.BUS_APPL_ID = 5
            AND ps.BUS_APPL_ID=ba.BUS_APPL_ID
            AND ba.APPL_NM = 'TSYS')
WHERE rnk=1

Comment: @mahen - I'm not sure what you're asking here.  If you partition by both `urer_prfle_id` and `bus_appl_id` then you will get one row for each distinct combination of `user_prfle_id` and `bus_appl_id`.  In your example, you want one row for each distinct `id` so you would partition only on `id`.  Adding `username` to the `order by` in your example would break the tie if there were two rows with the same `id` both with the latest `timestamp` value using the `username`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option using an aggregate function. This removes the sub-query from Justin's query but does mean that the `LAST` function needs to be added on every column that is brought back.

```
select 
  id, 
  max(username) keep (dense_rank last order by timestamp), 
  max(timestamp)
from my_table
group by id
```

Unfortunately the syntax of the LAST and FIRST functions are slightly odd with the need for an aggregate function (MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG etc) at the beginning of the command. This is confusing if the partition and ordering provide a deterministic set to work on but means that the result will be consistent otherwise.